# Changing link in Wordpress template

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

quite an intimidating place you got here!

Basically I'm pretty new to web design, only really ever building around existing Wordpress templates.

I'm building my own website here: http://www.acjjphotography.com/ and currently when you click on a portfolio thumbnail it opens a description and you have to click 'LEARN MORE' to see the full portfolio. I want to eliminate this middle part.

I usually solve things like this by lots and lots of trial and error, changing bits of files for hours until the right thing happens. But this is usually with CSS, rather than HTML or PHP which I guess this is?

So how would I go about eliminating that middle part where it opens the description? I want it to go straight to the full portfolio when the thumbail is clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to provide the code of the template that is responsible for main page. Maybe attach a screenshot of the template folder if you're not sure which file that is.

Comment: look in admin at which template is used for that part of site and then look in your theme folder to see how that php template file gets put together. Create a child theme so you can duplicate the original template and test it without impacting the original theme

Comment: Looking at your source code, the portfolio <a> tags are firing a Bootstrap modal. You would need to change those to the path of the intended page.
I can't really help you with Wordpress I'm afraid.
On a side note, the website doesn't work in Safari OS X.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the css here, it's in your html page, there's 2 links, one for the middle page and one for the portfolio, you must replace the first link by the "more" link. 
for exemple on your website (for JOOMSOLUTION) : the middle page is referring to `#portfolio-196`, and the "more" link is referring to http://www.acjjphotography.com/index.php/portfolio/joomsolution/"